# Relative Layout

Tags: android

I didn't understand very well RelativeLayout, I didn't understand why with this XML (it represent an item of a listview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfumatura_riga"
    >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/featured_new_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/no_foto" 

        />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/featured_new_image"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        >

        <TextView
            style="@style/featured_new_title"
            android:id="@+id/featured_city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"


        />

        <TextView
            style="@style/featured_name_country"
            android:id="@+id/featured_country"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />




    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            style="@style/featured_date"
            android:id="@+id/featured_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I meet this result, why too much margin at the bottom of the row?
[image]

Comment: If you tried to change the layout_height of the relative layout to wrap_content, does it work?

Comment: i dont get anything wrong in this xml.

Comment: I tried with that xandy, but doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

I would primarily look at two things:

1. In relative layout, change `android:layout_height="fill_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap content"`
2. I guess the background is just a gradient. However, if it's an image, then it is possible that it's too big and the whole row is stretched vertically.

Comment: Do you mean nr 2? If so, then just cut the image or use a gradient :). If it's already a gradient, then it won't help you much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks atl all!I solve it replacing the RelativeLaoyout with a LinearLayout, I share the solution and I hope to help someone who have the same issues:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/featured_new_image"
     android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/no_foto" 

    />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    >

    <TextView
        style="@style/featured_new_title"
        android:id="@+id/featured_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"


    />

    <TextView
        style="@style/featured_name_country"
        android:id="@+id/featured_country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />




</LinearLayout>

<TextView
        style="@style/featured_date"
        android:id="@+id/featured_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
    />
```